# Erro em código SQL subconsulta

Tags: sql

O meu erro é o seguinte

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource,
>   boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\projeto\BD\proj_detalhes.php on line
>   25

```
<?php
$base_dados = "crowdfunding";
$conexao = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($base_dados) or die(mysql_error());
$sql = "SELECT projeto.id, nome, limite, projeto.descricao FROM projeto,(SELECT valor, recompensa.descricao FROM recompensa, projeto WHERE projeto.id = id_projeto)";
$resultado = mysql_query($sql);
?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Projetos Atuais</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Detalhes de um Projeto<br /></h1>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td><strong>ID</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Nome</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Data Final</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Descricao</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Valor da Recompensa</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Descricao da Recompensa</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    while($dados = mysql_fetch_array($resultado)){
    $id = $dados['id'];
    $nome = $dados['nome'];
    $data = $dados['limite'];
    $descricao_proj = $dados['projeto.descricao'];
    $valor = $dados['valor'];
    $descricao_rec = $dados['recompensa.descricao'];

    echo "<tr>
        <td>$id</td>
            <td>$nome</td>
            <td>$data</td>
            <td>$descricao_proj</td>
        <td>$valor</td>
        <td>$descricao_rec</td>  
    </tr>";
}
?>
</table><br /><br />
<form action="menu1.php" method="get">
    <center><input name="botao" type="submit" value="Voltar"/></center>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: O erro é claro, a função `mysql_fetch_array() ` espera um `resource` e está recebendo um boolean. Provavelmente sua consulta está retornando `false`.

Comment: Por que você não usa `inner join` pra fazer essa query ai, ta muito estranha.

Comment: Tomei a liberdade de re-fazer essa consulta para você: SELECT projeto.id, projeto.nome, projeto.limite, projeto.descricao, recompensa.valor, recompensa.descricao
FROM projeto
INNER JOIN recompensa ON recompensa.id_projeto = projeto.id

Comment: Bruh, muda as suas funções `mysql_` pras funções `mysqli_`, por questões de suporte. a partir do PHP 5.5+ essas funções estão deprecadas e não existem mais no PHP 7